# html div is not taking full height

Tags: html, css

Hi below is my css & html,i'm trying to align two div in a webpage with full height(100%) but is not working

```
.left_menu
 {
   height:100% !important;
   width:30%;
   border:1px solid grey;
   float:left;
 }

.right_menu
{
  height:100% !important;
  width:70%;
  border:1px solid grey;
  float:right;
}
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="left_menu">
</div>
<div class="right_menu">
</div>
```

this code is not taking full height,please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set html,body min-height to 100%

Child occupies the height of parent so 100% height of parent will give 100% height to child

Considering that you div is direct child of html,body(if not then you need to maintain the height ratio with its parent)

```
html,body{
height:100%;
 min-height:100%; 
}
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is if the body is not the parent of the div.

Comment: @rob i gave idea about the happening, edited the answer

Comment: @AshokSri can you specify more about the problem or any fiddle?

Comment: @AshokSri why do you want to make content overflow, set min-height instead of height in right and left div it will increase automatically

Comment: @A.B,i don't want whole page scroll, need a scroll inside an div

Comment: i want a page like http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-goals

Comment: @AshokSri okay 
set overflow:scroll; in that div

Comment: in this page whole page is scrolling isnt it?

Comment: make separate question for it so that more people will see and answer and your time will be saved. i will look into this after comming back to work in a while @AshokSri

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display: inline-block;` and it should solve the problem (did for me)

Comment: Holy sh*it. you just saved my evening! I was pulling my hair already. Don't why this was the fix though...

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in your `border` properties as they are adding extra space. So, I am not sure if this fit best your needs, but I would do something like this:

```
.left_menu
 {
   height:100% !important;
   width:29%;
   border:1px solid grey;
   float:left;
 }

.right_menu
{
  height:100% !important;
  width:69%;
  border:1px solid grey;
  float:left;
}
```

**EDIT:**
This might be better solution, because previous one will work different for devices with different width(for small device `right_menu` goes under `left_menu`). Here I just specify `width` for `left_menu`.

```
 .left_menu
 {
  height:100% !important;
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid grey;
  float:left;
 }

 .right_menu
{
  height:100% !important;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the height of the div to 100% but 100% of what? It's always 100% of the parent element but what is the parent element of the div set to? My bet is you don't have it set to anything and the browser has no way of calculating what 100% of nothing is.

Comment: ,scroll is not working when content of the left or right get over flow,please suggestthe solution

Comment: @AshokSri You already selected the best answer. Perhaps this is another question to post or you need to deselect it if it doesn't answer your question.